# Strange validation behaviour of the charset with two html of the same template

Tags: html, validation, character-encoding

I have got two HTML documents based on the same template. I built both exactly the same and then changed the contents inside the divs. I'm using the DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional and the charset ISO-8859-15 (for Spanish language, you know accents and so on) in a meta tag inside the head. 
And when it comes to validation, one parses and the other doesn't, and I can't figure out why.
It complains about some accents in one of the documents that are also present in the other document which gets no complaints.
I find it funny, but there must be a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem, I just opened with the simple notepad the file that was giving me trouble and once opened there I could see that I had strange characters like **“** or **‰** in my code. I just removed them and wrote the contents properly and, of course, it passed the parser. I could not see those characters with my file opened from notepad++, that's why the parser error I was getting was so strange to me. 
I didn't set the encoding in my Notepad++ to ANSI and maybe that was the reason I couldn't see those odd characters.